# Spring MVC Resources not mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Following is my mvc-dispatcher.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/view/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
<context:component-scan base-package="in.codejava.personal.controllers" />
</beans>
```

Where am I going wrong? All static/* url's is being mapped by a 404 Controller that I created instead of the static resources.

WEB.XML

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>Personal Web Blogs</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!--    <servlet-mapping> -->
<!--        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name> -->
<!--        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern> -->
<!--    </servlet-mapping> -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If I remove the commented section it works properly.

Comment: You may need to include more information to help with debugging the issue - relevant entry for dispatcherservlet in web.xml file, any potential controllers mapping to the same path. Also, can you please include details of how your 404 controller gets executed.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen added Web.XML. The 404 Controller is just a @ requestMapping executed when none of the mappings are matched.

Comment: That sounds reasonable right @Akhil, you have said if you remove the commented section it works out well. In the commented out section you are registering another servlet mapping right - which servlet is that.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen but that works only for tomcat and jboss and couple of servers

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a punt and assume you are using a conventional directory structure for your JS, CSS, images resources, like this:

- `src/main/webapp/[js|css|images]`

In this case your `mvc:resources` should look like:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/" />
```

and you should reference them in your JSPs something like this: `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/foo.js"`

Comment: doesn't matter. Check WEB.XML and my description for that.

Comment: nickdos's answer pointed me to the right fix in my own resource mapping problem. His jsp contextPath reference was the key in my situation, which I had neglected. Check the basics first, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a new servlet mapping in my web.xml
`<servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>`

and then make reference to the resources path on my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```